# Re-open Detail View from List in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Not sure if this is a bug in SwiftUI (XCode 11.0 beta 3 (11M362v)) or I'm missing something here.

How can I re-open a DetailView using a PresentationLink in a List using SwiftUI?

Removing the List in the example below works as expected:

```swift
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
            PresentationLink(destination: DetailView()) {
                Text("Open Detail View")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView : View {
    @Environment(\.isPresented) var isPresented: Binding<Bool>

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Detail View")
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Details"), displayMode: .inline)
                .navigationBarItems(
                    trailing: Button(action: { self.isPresented?.value.toggle() }) {
                        Text("Close")
                    }
                )
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I get the same behavior when replacing PresentationLink with an implementation using Button:

```
Button(action: { self.showModal = true }) { ... }.presentation(modal: Modal?)
```

[image: Demo]